# OpenImaj - face detection - display found faces

Tags: java, face-detection, openimaj

I'm using OpenImaj to detect faces in an image.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.openimaj.image.FImage;
import org.openimaj.image.ImageUtilities;
import org.openimaj.image.MBFImage;
import org.openimaj.image.colour.Transforms;
import org.openimaj.image.processing.face.detection.DetectedFace;
import org.openimaj.image.processing.face.detection.FaceDetector;
import org.openimaj.image.processing.face.detection.HaarCascadeDetector;

public class FaceDetection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MBFImage image;
        try {
            image = ImageUtilities.readMBF(new FileInputStream("image.jpg"));
            FaceDetector<DetectedFace,FImage> fd = new HaarCascadeDetector(80);
            List<DetectedFace> faces = fd. detectFaces (Transforms.calculateIntensity(image));

            System.out.println(faces.size());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To display an image we can use DisplayUtilities class: DisplayUtilities.display(image);
However the found face is in type DetectedFace.

Do you know how to display the face which is in the DetectedFace type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get an image with getFacePatch().

The documentation is here http://openimaj.org/apidocs/index.html

Answer (score 3):

In addition to previous answer:

1. With `getFacePatch()` you get a face as `FImage`:

   ```
   final FImage faceFImage = face.getFacePatch();
   ```
2. Now this *faceFImage* needs to be converted to `BufferedImage`:

   ```
   final BufferedImage bufferedFaceImage = ImageUtilities.createBufferedImage(faceFImage);
   ```
3. Now this *bufferedFaceImage* can be displayed with:

   ```
   DisplayUtilities.display(bufferedFaceImage);
   ```